# TypeScript Sanity syntax error screams unexpected token

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, sanity

In my localhost it screams that there is a syntax error in my utils folders where I am fetching skills, I have a few more fetch files setup the same way but this one screams in the local host as such  [image: fetchSkills syntax error]

Next I ran my build to see what he terminal tells me Module '"sanity"' has no exported member 'defineConfig'. So I checked the version of sanity, tried updating it. error still occurred. Here is my sanity folder package.json [image: sanity folder package.json]

nothing screams at me in my sanity.config.ts file [image: sanity config]

Comment: Could you please write this:
```console.log(res);
console.log(res.ok);
console.log(res.status);```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that whatever `api/getSkills` route sends you is not valid json data. Check the data sent by the service.